# For locally running scala spray server, curl localhost works, but curl <local ip> gets "Connection refused"

Tags: linux, scala, curl, spray

Not sure what this issue has to do with spray specifically, but I tried to reproduce with a netty-based server, and curling the local ip seems to work fine. Does anyone know what might cause the following not to work even though it does work with a basic netty server:

```
$ ifconfig 
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <my mac address>  
          inet addr:172.16.16.31
...
...
...
$ curl localhost:8080/myPath
myContent
$ curl 172.16.16.31:8080/myPath
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.16.16.31 port 8080: Connection refused
```

Advice on how to troubleshoot this issue is also welcome.

Comment: I had the same problem, but was able to get a response when I used `127.0.0.1` instead of localhost.

Answer (score 2):

Found the issue. Answering here in case anyone else has the same problem. My spray server was initialized with a command like the following:

```
startServer(interface = "localhost", port = 8080) {
```

This specification of an interface appears to cause the issue. If I set it to be the Ipv4 address of the machine, then curling localhost fails and curling the ipv4 address works (still not working for ipv6 though).

Answer (score 0):

I got similar issue, change your interface to ::0 which supports both ipv4 and ipv6 address.

My code looks like below

```
IO(Http) ? Http.Bind(service, interface = "::0", port = 8080)
```

More : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spray-user/0kPXN1XVe0E